# How to create a looping function displaying whether number is odd or even in Sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I wanted to create a loop dependent on the value of one variable, whether it is odd or even, but the code displays an error. The idea is that if 'count' is even, then c is used as a variable. If 'count' is odd then a is used. The majority is extremely messy and I know it, but the question is why does the code display an error for the counting function and for the "else" part, showing a syntax error

```
    **#Importing the calculus library
import sympy


#Specifying and defining values of the function

print("Function?")
y = sympy.Function('y')
y = 0.5
x = sympy.symbols('x')
print("Absolute uncertainty?")
n = sympy.symbols('n')
n = 0.001
print("Degree of root?")
m = sympy.symbols('m')
m = 2
s = sympy.symbols('s')
f = sympy.Function('f')
f = (1+x)**(1/m)

#Calculating absolute relative error as the stopping variable

print(f"Stopping variable: {s}")


#Creating the loop
count = 1
a = sympy.Function('a')
a = sympy.diff(f)
af = a.subs(x,0)
j = sympy.Function('j')
j = 1+((1/sympy.factorial(count))*af)*x**(count)
def main():
    global a
    global af
    global count 
    global j 
    global s
    count = count+1
    b = sympy.Function('b')
    b = sympy.diff(a)
    bf = b.subs(x,0)
    r = sympy.Function('r')
    r = j+((1/sympy.factorial(count))*bf)*x**(count)
    
    g = sympy.is_even(count)
    g = ask(Q.even(count))
    if g == True:
    
        count = count+1
        a = b
        af = a.subs(x,0)
        j = r+(1/sympy.factorial(count))*af*x**(count)

  
    main()
    
    else:
        ans = r
        res_ans = ans.subs(x, y-1)
        print(f"Answer: {res_ans}")       
main()



**
```

Comment: The error is raised when you use both spaces and tabs to indent your code. Make sure you use only speces or tabs, but do not mix them.

Comment: sadly, still I cannot make it work as now it does not see the attribute is_given  in the sympy library although the entire library was added. Did they change it by any chance?

Comment: I can not further help you in this case technically, since I just have heard SymPy from you. You could edit the question and post clearer code to help someone more understand the problem in order to give the solution.

Comment: I think you need to spend more time learning basic python before trying to use `sympy`. Line pairs like `y = sympy.Function('y'); y = 0.5` show a lack of basic understanding.  The first doesn't 'declare' the type of `y`.  The 2nd line assigns a number to the variable, not a value to the `function`.

Comment: As for syntax, I see a spurious `main()` between the `if` and `else` clauses.  Again a basic python error.

Comment: If you call `main()` inside a function `def main()` it would be a recursive function, which I am not sure that you wanto to achieve. I am agree with @hpaulj, that it would be better to first understand the pyton basic syntax before you create a complex code.

Answer (score 0):

I can fix the code and do not produce any error(s) as follow

```py
# Importing the calculus library
import sympy

# Specifying and defining values of the function
print("Function?")
y = sympy.Function('y')
y = 0.5
x = sympy.symbols('x')

print("Absolute uncertainty?")
n = sympy.symbols('n')
n = 0.001

print("Degree of root?")
m = sympy.symbols('m')
m = 2
s = sympy.symbols('s')
f = sympy.Function('f')
f = (1+x)**(1/m)

# Calculating absolute relative error as the stopping variable
print(f"Stopping variable: {s}")

# Creating the loop
count = 1
a = sympy.Function('a')
a = sympy.diff(f)
af = a.subs(x,0)
j = sympy.Function('j')
j = 1+((1/sympy.factorial(count))*af)*x**(count)

def main():
    global a
    global af
    global count 
    global j 
    global s
    count = count+1
    b = sympy.Function('b')
    b = sympy.diff(a)
    bf = b.subs(x,0)
    r = sympy.Function('r')
    r = j+((1/sympy.factorial(count))*bf)*x**(count)
    
    g = sympy.simplify(count).is_even
    g = sympy.ask(sympy.simplify(count).is_even)
    
    if g == True:
        count = count+1
        a = b
        af = a.subs(x,0)
        j = r+(1/sympy.factorial(count))*af*x**(count)
  
    else:
        ans = r
        res_ans = ans.subs(x, y-1)
        print(f"Answer: {res_ans}")

main()
```

by removing the call of `main()` in the function `def main():`. But since I do not know what you want to achieve and lack of knowledge in SymPy, I can not further help.

You can see results on https://github.com/dudung/py-jupyter-nb/blob/main/src/so/75201156.ipynb in the **all parts** section, after debuggin per part (**part 1** and **part 2**).

And if `main()` is still put befre `else`, after fix the indentation, it does not stop since it call itself recursively.

Comment: Drop the double assignments!  ``m=2` throws away the previous `m=symbols...` assignment.